# Flattening Linq Group query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

I have a list of data like so:

```
ID AddressPurpose Address ...
1  L
1  P
2  L
2  P
3  P
3  L
4  P
4  L
5  P
6  L
```

I want to be able to filter the data so that for each unique number if there is a P row then it is returned else the L row is returned. So the data will look like this:

```
ID AddressPurpose Address ...
1  P
2  P
3  P
4  P
5  P
6  L
```

At the moment I have this query which works fine:

```
var query = from c in list
            orderby c.AddressPurpose descending
            group c by c.ID
            into g
                select g;

var finalList = new List<Company>();
foreach (var list in query)
{
    finalList.Add(list.First());
}
return finalList;
```

**Is there a better way to do this without using the extra foreach?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you `select` `g.First()` instead?

Comment: You must've been typing that as I was editing my own respose, lc! +1!

Comment: I guess so. I like your nested queries too, they're reusable anytime you need to iterate through complicated queries.

Comment: Thanks. That works great. I kind of understand the "into g" part now.

Comment: You may also be interested in this article http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1271255&seqNum=3 where it talks about the into keyword

Answer (score 10):

You could always nest your queries:

```
var query =
    from i in (
        from c in list 
        orderby c.AddressPurpose descending 
        group c by c.ID into g 
        select g)
    select i.First();

return query;
```

I'm sure this isn't the only way to do it (or possibly even the best), but it does wrap your "foreach" up into the one query.

**Edit**

In fact, you can simplify this down to:

```
var query = from c in list
            orderby c.AddressPurpose descending
            group c by c.ID into g
            select g.First();
```

That seems to give the right result.

Answer (score 2):

```
var finalList = list
  .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(c => c.AddressPurpose).First())
  .ToList();
```